# How to parse a text file for string pattern and count unique entries?

Tags: bash, parsing, split

I have a logfile that contains login data, and I need to generate a report that summarizes all of the failed login attempts and organize it by the user.  A line from the file looks like:

```
Jan 21 19:22:23 localhost sshd[1234]: Failed password for USER from 127.0.0.1 port 12345 ssh2  #IPs and such obscured, obviously
```

And it's the `USER` from the line that I need to count and summarize. The pattern is always `Failed password for USER` so that helps, but I can't do `awk -F` or other string splitting stuff due to the amount of other junk on the line.

How can I count each failed login and total them up per user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU grep, try this:

```
grep -Po "Failed password for \K.*?(?= from)" logfile.log | sort | uniq -c
```

`-P` enables perl regexes, allowing for things like `\K`.
`-o` Prints only the matched part, instead of whole lines that contain a match.
`\K` makes grep forget the part it matched before, so that it won't appear in the output.
`.*?` matches USER. Only this part will be printed.
`(?= from)` is a lookahead needed to determine when USER ends.

The `grep` part prints USER for every failed login attempt of USER. Now we only need to count the occurrences for each user. This is done with the idiom `sort | uniq -c`.

The final output looks like this:

```
      7 adam
      2 bob
     14 claire
```

The output is sorted by user names. To sort by the number of failed attempts, append `| sort -nr` to the command.

Comment: I believe you have a typo, you should add the Input_file name after your `grep` command.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 You could add it at the beginning, too: `<foo.log grep -Po ...`

Comment: This is perfect!  It worked great!  My only question, how can I get them to sort from largest count to smallest?

Comment: @user3066571 Glad to hear that. You can sort the result with `sort -nr` again. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '/Failed password for/{gsub(/.*for | from.*/,"");a[$0]++} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/Failed password for/{
  gsub(/.*for | from.*/,"");
  a[$0]++
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    print i,a[i]}
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl solution:

```
perl -nle '$seen{$1}++ if /Failed password for (\S+) from /; END { print "$_: $seen{$_}" for sort keys %seen }'
```

The idea is to use a regex to extract the username from matching lines, use that to build a histogram in a hash (mapping usernames to counts), and print it all out at the end.